# Real Analysis: Show that the Taylor expression converges at every point.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that the function $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has derivatives of all orders and that

\begin{cases}
F'(x)-F(x)=0, & \text{for all $x$} \\
F(0)=2.
\end{cases}
Find a formula for the coefficients of the $n$th Taylor polynomial for F at $x=0$. Show that the Taylor expansion converges at every point.

I have done the first half:
 Re-write the equation to be $F'(x)=F(x)$. Then we have $F^k(x)=F^{(k-1)}(x)$ and $F^k(0)=F^{(k-1)}(0)=2$. The coefficient of the $n$th Taylor polynomial at $x=0$ is $\frac{2}{k!}$.

Which I hope is correct, but I need help showing that the Taylor expression converges at every point. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have $$F(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty {2x^n\over n!}.$$
Apply the ratio test to see this converges for all real values (complex as well) values of $x$.

Comment: Ah yes thank you! I forgot about using the ratio test, the section this question is from was only 1.5 pages so I knew I had to be missing something!

Answer (score 0):

$F$ is easy to find (the ODE is linear with constant coefficients): $F(x) = 2e^x$.  Then $a_n = F^{(n)}(0)/n!$, which should be easy to find.  Applying the ratio test to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, that power series converges for any $x$.  Am I missing something?